# Disable user interaction when didSelectRowIndexPathRow is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

So when the user selects a row, I put the selection on another thread for performance reasons. When I take it off of the main thread, the row is deselected for a few seconds and the pushed to the next view. Those few seconds when the row is deselected and taken off of the main thread, the user has the option to rapidly click the row again, and again - forcing the app to potentially crash. So my question is how would I deselect user interaction on the table row inside of the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? Now, please acknowledge I don't want to disable user interaction before the a row is selected. I only am looking to disable user interaction on the cell after the row has been selected. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest an instance-level `bool` (something like `processingRow`) and enable it when you tap on a row. Then, when the background thread finishes, disable it. Make it so that as long as it is enabled, you can't select another row (or the same row, or however you want it to work).

Comment: So your saying make the scope of the cell object global so I can call the `processingRow` method and disable user interaction in the `processingRow` method?

Comment: No, I'm saying add a single `bool` that knows if you're processing. I guess if you need to process multiple rows at once and only want to disable a single row as you process it, you could either create an array of `bool` with one for each row, or keep an array of `indexPath` objects and add your current `indexPath` when you start processing and remove it when you finish so if your `indexPath` already exists in that array when you select a row, don't do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

Make an instance variable `NSIndexPath selectedPath;`

Add

```
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
selectedPath = indexPath;
```

to your didSelectRowAtIndexPath and in performSegueWithIdentifier (assuming you are using storyboards) add

```
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedPath] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```